# Using .htaccess for a variable folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, directory

I am having a little trouble with using .htaccess for what I need it to do.

This is the URL of the webpage:

```
http://example.com/folder/$1/topic.php?id=$2
```

The only two things that change are $1 and $2.

I was using this code, but I cannot seem to get it to work with the variable folder.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ topic.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ topic.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^folder/$1/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ folder/$1/topic.php?id=$2
RewriteRule ^folder/$1/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ folder/$1/topic.php?id=$2
```

I may have made some mistake with the syntax but I cannot seem to figure it out.

The browser URL will change to look like:

```
http://example.com/folder/$1/topic/$2
```

Thank you for your time ^.^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yay! user-sama.

I think you need to escape  `$1`, just give it some backslash ninja punch:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/\$1/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ folder/$1/topic.php?id=$2
```

Or it might be:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ folder/$1/topic.php?id=$2
```

^__^

Yeah, i need to explain what's going on, so what's between parentheses in the left becomes `$` on the right, the number that comes after `$` is the present order of parentheses. So:

```
#             1st   2nd   3rd        1st────┐    2nd    ┌──────3rd   
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*)$ file.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3
```

These parentheses blocks are called capture block, it's RegExp.